# Google Sheets Entry Default

Tags: google-sheets

Looking for how to make entry of currency to default to cents e.g. .15 when user enters 15 - current result is 15.00 - using a function to divide by 100 to force cents is not the solution because entries may also be dollars and cents.

Comment: If the entries may also be dollars and cents, then what you're asking doesn't really make sense. What if the user wanted $15 - current? How would you differentiate that 15 from your example of 15 - current where you want to treat the 15 as cents?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @SeanKladek I don't think that the word "current" is any part of the data entry. The OP is referring to the "current result". Having said that, I think the OP needs to read up on [formatting numbers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: if I understand correctly what you said, you want two different outputs for one input (e.g. in case you write 15, should the program write 15.00 or 0.15?). This is not possible. As @player0 said, please provide a sanitized copy of your sheet with an example of the desired output